# Naming objects which implement delegates to cleanup UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I noticed that some of my view controllers have become pretty big and I'd like to avoid the MVC (Massive View Controller).

I found that my view controllers often implement a lot of delegates from other view controllers which I may or may not present at runtime. Also they are often datasources for table- or collectionviews.

Its not to hard to refactor the view controllers and put the datasources and delegates into their own structs or classes and then just have a bunch of lazy optional properties which I can pass around.

**My problem is**: I'm really bad at naming things and I wonder if there are some **best practices** on how to name the delegates and datasource objects.

Here are a few examples of delegates and datasources I currently implement in my viewcontroller but which I want to put in their own objects:

- UITableViewDataSource
- UITableVIewDelegate
- UICollectionViewDataSource
- UICollectionViewDelegate
- ImagePickerDelegate
- DatePickerKeyboardDelegate
- KeyboardAccessoryToolbarDelegate
- AControllerDelegate
- BControllerDelegate
- CControllerDelegate

And my view controller are named after what they do, followed by Controller (I don't like to name them ViewController because it makes their name even longer):

- ImagesController
- FoodController
- StoreController
- AController
- BController
- CController

Okay so now to an example. `AController` could push `BController` onto the navigation stack. `AController` currently implements the `BControllerDelegate` but does not actually need to do that. Instead, `AController` *could* hold a object which implements the `BControllerDelegate` and just configures the delegate before it pushes `BController` and sets `BController`s delegate.

But how would I name the object which implements the `BControllerDelegate` and how would I name the variable which holds this object in my `AController`?

```
class AController: UIViewController {
    let whatsMyName = WhatsMyName()
}

struct WhatsMyName: BControllerDelegate {}
```

**Update**

Yesterday I started refactoring a few of my view controllers. As also suggested by danh (I hope I understood you right), I currently let the view controller still be the delegate of my datasources. Though I now have separate datasource objects and I currently configure everything like so:

```
struct MyModel {
    var name: String
    init(name: String) { self.name = name }
}

class MyModelDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {
    let myModelCollection: [MyModel] = [MyModel(name:"Hello"), MyModel(name:"World")]

    init(tableView: UITableView) {
        //setup tableview, register cells, set row height, etc.
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myModelCollection.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel.text = myModelCollection[indexPath.row].name
        return cell
    }
}

protocol MyViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func myViewController(_ myViewController: MyViewController, picked: MyModel)
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    weak var myViewControllerDelegate: MyViewControllerDelegate?
    lazy var myModelDataSource: MyModelDataSource = {
        return MyModelDataSource(tableView: self.tableView)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.dataSource = myModelDataSource
        tableView.delegate = self

        if myViewControllerDelegate == nil { delegate = self }
    }
}

extension MyViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        myViewControllerDelegate?.myViewController(self, picked: myModelDataSource.myModelCollection[indexPath.row])
    }
}

extension MyViewController: MyViewControllerDelegate {
    func myViewController(_ myViewController: MyViewController, picked: MyModel) {
        //Perform drill down
    }
}

extension SomeOtherViewController: MyViewControllerDelegate {
    func myViewController(_ myViewController: MyViewController, picked: MyModel) {
        //Perform picking of item and dismiss/pop myViewController
    }
}
```

The deal with this is, that it probably still light years away from being perfect. I think actually the viewcontroller could or maybe even sholud still be the delegate **and** datasource for **every** tableview (keep in mind that you might have multipe tableview outlets and therefore also multiple datasource objects).

It could then just forward the datasource functions to the appropriate datasource object which is stored as lazy instance variable. That would allow me to have datasources which only have 1 section and "stitch together" multiple datasources into one tableview by using a datasource per section (I hope that you know what I mean).

Also I decided to avoid subclassing the controller for the sake of picking entries as suggested by danh. Instead I set the controller as it's own delegate if no other controller wants to do the job.

This is like a default implementation which basically says "If nobody wants to be my delegate, I'm a drill down controller. Otherwise my delegate will know what to do with me" and though this example only makes use of didSelectRowAt: in reality I delegate often also other things like accessoryTypeFor: and custom functions like when I use the controller as a picker to de-/select multiple entries at once, displaying selected entries with checkmarks an so on.

Hopefully I understood danh correctly and I call the datasources in my viewcontroller after the model they hold together with "DataSource" whereas the DataSource object itself holds a "xxxCollection". Please correct me if I'm wrong. :)

So to sum up, the "naming convention" or "best practice" (as there is probably not a real one besides what we just came up with) is:

- Be consistent with the naming
- Make the name descriptive and don't violate common language agreements even if it makes the name a little longer (e. g. it's probably better to name it MyVeryOwnSuperDuperCoolViewController rather than MyVeryOwnSuperDuperCoolController if the controller is in fact a UIViewController except if you have very good reasons to do so and if you do, do it consistently)
- Name your DataSource after the model it has a collection of (e. g. MyModelDataSource)
- The DataSource should have a collection of the model (e. g. var myModelCollection: [MyModel]

I hope I haven't forgotten something. Still interested if somebody has written down something about this topic somewhere which could be considered a best practice or best-practice-suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with your thinking that reducing vc size by factoring is a good idea, but whether you factor something, and by what means should depend on semantics.

Let me suggest a pattern with this example: Say your app is about driving, and somewhere within it, user must select a car.  The view controller in this case might be (ought to be) named `CarPickerViewController`.  Why? "Car" is obvious, "Picker" is a norm borrowed from elsewhere in the SDK culture, and "ViewController" is practically a rule (which you've opted to violate, but at least you've done so deliberately, reasonably, consistently, etc.).

Certainly, the most important noun in this story is a `Car`, a thing with wheels and a motor, and so on.  But there's also an important *collective noun*, representing a group of zero or more cars.  If they were geese, we'd call it a "gaggle", but my rule for nouns that don't have an existing specific collective noun is to add a collective suffix, as in `CarCollection`.

To recap so far, we have `CarPickerViewController`, which holds a `CarCollection` which wraps an array of `Car`.  And certainly, that `CarCollection` can (should) conform to `UITableViewDatasource`.

What about the delegate?  Here again, imo, we should be driven by semantics, not file arrangement.  Probably, only job the delegate has in this example is to learn about selection in the table view.  We could, even though it would be poor design, just let the presenting view controller conform to the table view delegate protocol this way:

```
// in CarPickerViewController.h
@property(weak,nonatomic) id<UITableViewDelegate> delegate;

// in CarPickerViewController.m
- (void)setDelegate:(id<UITableViewDelegate>) delegate {
    self.tableView.delegate = delegate;
}
```

The presenting view controller would then set itself as the delegate, and implement `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, not crazy, but passing it a tableView?  Which tableView?  The better answer here is a new protocol, defined by the picker:

```
// in CarPickerViewController.h
@protocol CarPickerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)carPicker:(CarPickerViewController *)vc didPickCar:(Car *)car;
@end
// in CarPickerViewController.m (which remains the table view delegate)
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Car *car = self.carArray[indexPath.row];
    [self.delegate carPicker:self didPickCar:car];
}
```

Should we factor out an another class to be the `UITableViewDatasource` which does this translation?  I say, no way!  So to recap again:

```
CarPickerViewController - conforms to UITableViewDelegate
CarCollection - conforms to UITableViewDatasource
Car - a humble model
```

Just a little more:  Let's say there was a drill-down interface where we could browse car details.  I think we'll end up renaming our "picker" class to be more generically, `CarViewController`.  It will have a table view of cars and not much else.  A subclass, our original `CarPickerViewController`, will continue to implement the one method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` as it did before, but it's superclass implementation will perform drill-down navigation on the same method.

I could go on, but I fear I've gone on too long.  Hope this gives enough sense of an approach that you can apply in your app.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'm actually doing it partly like you suggest already. I like that you say the naming convetion of the datasource object should be xxxCollection. That makes very much sense. You have not went to far. I'd be happy to hear more from what you think on this. Let me update my original question with what I've learned so far and how I do things at the very moment.

Answer (score 0):

For your above way, you are going to write a lot of boilerplate codes and make it even more complicated.
There is a good practice to organize your Delegate is to use `extension` in stead of the above way.
For example:

```
class AController: UIViewController {

}

extension AController: BControllerDataSource {

}

extension AController: CControllerDelegate {

}
```

You even do not need to put in one file, you can separate it if your ViewController is too long. For example.
`AController+BControllerDatasource.swift`
`AController+CControllerDelegate.swift`
It makes ViewController look clean and keep related logic functions in separate groups.

Comment: I'm already implementing delegates in extension though not in their own files. That could be an option. However, I still like the idea of giving away responsibilities from my view controllers, especially if there is no need for them being involved. Also it could improve reusability if I had a separate datasource which I could use in different places. For example I could have a datasource object to display images and I could use the same datasource without a filter in a images controller to display all images or I could initialize it with a filter to display images in another view controller.

Comment: I think the problem with extensions which implement delegates becomes the most obvious when you start having more than one table-/collectionview per viewcontroller. then you stuff you cellForRowAt: functions with if/switch to decide on a per tableview which cell to return. with separate objects as datasource for each table-/collection view, you don't have to care because each datasource object is only reliable for one table-/collectionview

Comment: Yes. it is nice that you come up with `Composition` idea. If just about naming, you can name it following the rule you name ViewController. For example, `struct ImageDataSource : UITableViewDataSource` or `struct ImageDelegate: UITableViewDelegate`.

Comment: Do you know of some documentation or best practices for naming? :)

Comment: However, I think that you will surely going to write a lot of boilerplate codes and implement many things manually.

Comment: There are several coding styles on Github. Personally, I prefer Raywenderlich's: https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide.

Comment: While I like this style-guide, I must either be blind or it just does not give me an answer to my problem. :(